# Muting all sound for a streaming video in Actionscript-2

Tags: actionscript-2, cs3, netconnection

So I'm trying to mute a streamed video. For now I'm working with one in the same directory.

```
var flvURL = 'flvInThisDirectory.flv'; 
var netConn:NetConnection = new NetConnection();   
netConn.connect(null);   
var netStream:NetStream = new NetStream(netConn);   
my_video2.attachVideo(netStream); 
    netStream.setBufferTime(0);
    netStream.play(flvURL);  

    //all of the below are different, supposedly valid attempts to mute sound for 
    //this stream.. none of them work

    var nsst = new SoundTransform(0);
    nsst.volume = 0;
    netStream.soundTransform=nsst;
    netStream.fromSrvr.attachAudio(false);
    var so = new Sound(netStream); 
    so.setVolume(0);    
    stopAllSounds();
```

But there's still sound. This is the same if the URL is remote, too. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Woops.

"var so = new Sound(netStream);"

Make this into

"var so = new Sound();"

not even gonna give myself a point for this one.